# How do I add axis labels and a title to a matplotlib integrated into a tkinter window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have searched the docs and I cannot figure out how to label the axis and title of a plot.

This is my current code:

```
font = {'size'   : 40}
plot.rc('font', **font)

fig = Figure(figsize=(32, 31), dpi=20)

plot.figure(facecolor='yellow')
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=graphFrame)  # A tk.DrawingArea.

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, graphFrame)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

def plotgraph(x, y):
    fig.clear()
    fig.add_subplot(111).plot(x, y, linewidth=9.0)
    canvas.draw_idle()
    
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)

testx = np.ndarray.tolist(np.arange(1,41))
testy = np.ndarray.tolist(np.random.randint(40, size=40))

def updateCurrentGraph(gx, gy, ylabel, xlabel, title):
    plotgraph(gx, gy)
    
    axis.set_ylabel(ylabel)
    axis.set_xlabel(xlabel)
    axis.set_title(title)
    
    testx.pop(0)
    testx.append(int(testx[-1] + 1))
    
    testy.pop(0)
    testy.append(int(randint(1, 40)))
    
    root.after(500, updateCurrentGraph, gx, gy, ylabel, xlabel, title)

updateCurrentGraph(testx, testy, "Loss", "Time", "Loss over time")

root.mainloop()
```

I tried putting

```
axis = fig.add_subplot(111)
```

into the plotgraph function as a variable declaration, but that just raised an error that axis wasn't declared (even if I ran the plotgraph function to declare it). Running the program as shown above works fine, just the labels aren't showing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `plot.title`, `axis.set_xlabel`, and `axis.set_ylabel`